ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC after migration problem
I migrated my project from ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4 to ASP.NET Core 8 MVC, and tested it locally, and everything is ok.
But when I deploy it to IIS server, RedirectToAction throws this error:

This page isn’t working  project is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500 also shows ispect source: No resource with given URL found.

The iis server was previously .NET 4 and the corresponding configurations were later installed on .net 8, so any changes may be required?
Example:
public IActionResult Index() 
{
    // Redirecting to "About" action in this controller 
    return RedirectToAction("About"); 
}

